# Preference change listener but AFTER the internal state has changed android

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, preferencefragmentcompat

I have a SettingsFragment which extends PreferenceFragmentCompat and the preference.xml

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        preferenceManager.findPreference<Preference>(USER_CLOUD_PROXY)?.let {
            it.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { _, _ ->
                // mainViewModel.resetConnection()
                true
            }
        }

        return view
    }

}
```

and xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="User settings">
        <SwitchPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:key="user_cloud_proxy"
            android:title="Use cloud proxy" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

The switch button indicates with which URL my app has to connect to a webSocket server. So when the user changes the switch state i want to reset the connection through a function. Later in the function i read the sharedPreference value to choose the URL.
However, the `it.setOnPreferenceChangeListener` get called **before the internal state has changed**, which means that i dont read the newValue, but the old.

Is there a callback that gets called AFTER the internal value has changed?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener

Comment: that does not answer the question...

Comment: I didn't say its the answer I just wanted to confirm you are using this only right ?

Comment: because as per documentation you should get newValue

Comment: i can get the newValue inside the callback but i want to read it afterwards from the sharedPreferences and not by passing it as a parameter. However, i didnt find any solution so i passed it like a parameter :P

Comment: `android:enabled="true"` is non-semse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `OnPreferenceChangeInternalListener.onPreferenceChange` which is Called when this Preference has changed, but this callback is for internal usage only.

[image]

[image]

So yes, there is no other callback that gets called after the internal value has changed.
`OnPreferenceChangeListener.onPreferenceChange` is the only one you can use.

One thing you can do, if you don't want to call the function directly from the callback taking the newValue from it, then you can save the new value in SharedPref manually and then call the function which can use your logic of reading the value from sharedpref and proceeding further.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to dinkar_kumar's answer you can try to implement `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and I think you can use `onSharedPreferenceChanged` to use your logic further.

Comment: As per java doc of `onSharedPreferenceChanged`            **Called when a shared preference is changed, added, or removed. This may be called even if a preference is set to its existing value.**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, well informed! i will do this the way u propose. Seems fine

Answer (score 0):

As I have tested, if you have an async task, it will be run after the internal state has changed like below:

Kotlin Sample Code:

```kotlin
Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { _, _ ->
    afterChange()
    true
}


fun afterChange() {
    // coroutine async task
    MainScope().launch {
        // It will run after the preference has been changed.
    }
}
```